# Automate JIRA user creation using Groovy Script

Tags: groovy, automation, jira

We are continuously receiving user creation/removal in our JIRA instance as the team is growing.

I am looking for possible options to automate this using groovy script.

Currently, we are having a separate project in JIRA handling these requests. Team will raise the tickets with user name, required roles & Manager will be approve request in the project and then it will be picked by JIRA admin to create/remove the users.

Then JIRA admin will close the ticket.

I am looking to automate the JIRA admin work, Once the ticket is raised by team & moved to a certain status(like Approval), JIRA should create the users automatically. How this can be achieved using groovy script?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the Jira API to do what you want. The [Jira REST API Reference](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/rest/v3/intro/) has everything you need.

For user creation, a POST request to the `rest/api/3/user` endpoint should work while a DELETE request to the same endpoint should remove the user. [This guide by Atlassian](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirakb/how-to-create-a-user-on-jira-using-rest-api-1087532594.html) has detailed information on creating users via that endpoint.

The REST API reference also has endpoints to automatically transition the state of the Jira issue. A GET request to the `/rest/api/3/issue/{issueIdOrKey}/transitions` endpoint shows you all possible transitions for an issue while a POST request to the same endpiont allows you to transition the issue.

Comment: @M B  Is there any Groovy script to do this activity ?

Comment: There are no pre-written scripts to do this for you. Take a look at [this article](https://www.baeldung.com/groovy-web-services) on how you can call APIs (including the Jira API) using Groovy.

Answer (score 0):

I have used below groovy script to create the user and add to particular group

```
import com.atlassian.jira.component.ComponentAccessor

def userName = "user2"
def groupNametoAdd = "jira-servicedesk-users"
def userToAdd = ComponentAccessor.getUserManager().getUserByName(userName)
def groupName = ComponentAccessor.getGroupManager().getGroup(groupNametoAdd)


if (!userToAdd) {
    log.error("User doesn't exist")
    return
}

if (ComponentAccessor.getGroupManager().getGroupsForUser(userName).contains(groupName)) {
    log.error("User: $userToAdd.username already in the group: $groupName.name")
    return
}



if(!groupName) {
    log.error("Group doesn't exist")
} else {
    ComponentAccessor.groupManager.addUserToGroup(userToAdd, groupName)
    log.error("User: $userToAdd.username added to the group: $groupName.name")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you run approvals in Jira Service Management project (previously known as Jira Service Desk) then you can take advantage of build in Automation for Jira with two steps:

1. When: Approval completed
2. Then: Send web request

Example:
[image: Approval Automation rule]

Web request can do API call to create user, documentation is here:
https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/rest/v3/api-group-users/#api-rest-api-3-user-post

In web request you can interpolate data from issue.
If you have custom field "New user email" then you can use it in request payload:
[image: Create user web request]

What you may need to know:

- [Include Authorization header with access token.](https://support.atlassian.com/atlassian-account/docs/manage-api-tokens-for-your-atlassian-account/)
- [Automation for Jira with Jira REST API example](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Jira-articles/Automation-for-Jira-Send-web-request-using-Jira-REST-API/ba-p/1443828)
- [Find custom field smart value `{{...}}`](https://support.atlassian.com/cloud-automation/docs/find-the-smart-value-for-a-field/#finding-your-smart-value)

"Approval completed" - trigger is only available in Jira Service Management projects. Other Jira projects do not have build-in approval management solution.In case you would like to run approvals in other Jira project type you could use [Approval Path for Jira](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1220490/approval-path-for-jira?tab=overview).
You can put Web Request and call Automation for Jira via webhook:
[image: Approval Path for Jira - create user with webhook to Jira Automation]

Jira Automation rule will be triggered but Approval Path webhook / http request.